# Do I need to write a full test for overloads?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

Assume the following method overloads:

```
public string SayHello(string identifier)
{
    return $"Hello {identifier}";
}

public string SayHello(long identifier)
{
    return SayHello(identifier.ToString());
}
```

I would write a test for `SayHello(string identifier)` like this:

```
Assert.Equal("Hello Max", SayHello("Max"))
```

What about `SayHello(long identifier)` ? Of course I could write

```
Assert.Equal("Hello 123", SayHello(123))
```

but imagine the logic for SayHello would be far more complex. Then I basically would have to write the same unit test twice with only slight changes. So, is there any better approach? Maybe just check if / assert that `SayHello(long identifier)` ONLY calls `SayHello(identifier.toString())` ? Is that possible?

Comment: It’s best to write a test method for each scenario how the method may be used in regards to overloads, especially as you indicated,  SayHello would be far more complex.

Comment: How the overloads are implemented is inconsequential in this case. The tests are meant to assert "that given a known input, a desired output/behavior is expected".  Each is tested to assert expected behavior. If the implementation of one is modified, the unit test can be used to verify desired behavior.

Comment: If multiple tests have similar arrangements then aggregate that setup in a common member (DRY) with the necessary modifications for differing arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, since neither of the methods are virtual and both are in the same class, you can't test `SayHello(long)` without testing `SayHello(string)`. There's no way to intercept the call to `SayHello(string)` without changing the code (or maybe perform some really ugly hacks). You could of course introduce some callback interface in there or some unit-test-only flags, but all of that requires adjusting the code so that it's testable the way you want it. Personally, I'm not a fan of increasing the complexity of some code pieces just for the sake of testability.

So unless the methods are *really* complex, I would just go with testing them together, maybe by using a theory approach (combinatorial test cases). Note that if you one time change your `SayHello(string)` to `return $"Bye {identifier}";` you'd have to change all test cases anyway.